# Cookie not set in browser from HTTPS response

Tags: node.js, angular, angular5

angular v5x,
node v8.11.1,
google chrome v72.0.3626.109 64-bit window 8

Able to get cookie at client side if client and server on same domain for example **https:example.com**
and not able to get cookie if client and server is on different domain like client is on domain https://sub1.example1.com  and server is on domain https://sub2.example2.com

Allowed CORS configured in server:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.get('origin'));
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, DELETE");
res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
```

Attaching cookie with HTTPS response object

```
var cookieConfigOptions = {
    "maxAge": 946080000,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": true,
    "signed": true,
    "domain": ".sub1.example1.com"
};

res.cookie("token", "80444cd0-38fa-11e9-9c54-f3ac2c85d660_Aaaaa_Bbb_CC", cookieConfigOptions);
```

REST API response headers:

```
[Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
   { 'x-powered-by': [ 'X-Powered-By', 'Express' ],
     'access-control-allow-credentials': [ 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true' ],
     'access-control-allow-origin': [ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin','https://sub1.example1.com' ],
     'access-control-allow-headers': [ 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' ],
     'access-control-allow-methods': [ 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT, GET, DELETE' ],
     'access-control-expose-headers': [ 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers', '*' ],
     'x-ratelimit-limit': [ 'X-RateLimit-Limit', 5000 ],
     'x-ratelimit-remaining': [ 'X-RateLimit-Remaining', 4999 ],
     'set-cookie':
      [ 'Set-Cookie',
        'token=s%3A80444cd0-38fa-11e9-9c54-f3ac2c85d660_Aaaaa_Bbb_CC.PhB51SpDR%2FycSc2NVYy7mJ9WbjcgzHrAqGKrL95GppQ; Max-Age=946080000; Domain=.sub1.example1.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 17 Feb 2049 12:40:15 GMT; Secure' ],
     etag: [ 'ETag', 'W/"7d-r04KVX+lvHV/X56rSN84FzKivtU"' ] } }
```

Added withCredentials option in interceptor in ng5 code while requesting api.

```
req = req.clone({ withCredentials: true });
```

In response header **set-cookie** available but not able to get in browser using angular client.
Please suggest me what is missing.
Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to read the cookies. It would be a big security risk: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders#Return_value

Comment: Hi Andrei Tătar, thanks for the quick reply. I am not getting cookie header manually. Actually we want browser automatically set cookie with domain once cookie available in response from server. It works if using same sub domain but not works if sub domain of client and server are different.

Comment: That's because you would be able to do CORS requests (on sites that allow it and the user is authenticated) and read the user cookie.